# Ordering bar chart by value in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble creating a bar chart utilizing `ggplot2` that is sorted by value.

I understand that I can order the data frame by the value and then plot it. However, `ggplot2` seems to ignore the ordering.

I am using the following code:

```
df$Frequency <- factor(dft$Frequency,  levels = df$Frequency[order(df$Frequency)])
df


# Plot the data
plot = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Word , y=Frequency, label=Frequency)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(size = 5, position = position_stack(vjust = 1.04)) +
  coord_flip()
plot
```

The data looks like this:

```
   ID Word Frequency
1  70    a       194
2  48    b       116
3 139    c       104
4 293    d        87
5  12    d        87
```

And I get the following plot:
[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reorder` to order you bars. You can use the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(70, 48, 139, 293, 12),
                 Word = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                 Frequency = c(194, 116, 104, 87, 87))

plot = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=reorder(Word, -Frequency) , y=Frequency, label=Frequency)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(size = 5, position = position_stack(vjust = 1.04)) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "Word")
plot
```

Output:

[image]

Use `reorder(Word, Frequency)`:

```
plot = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=reorder(Word, Frequency) , y=Frequency, label=Frequency)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(size = 5, position = position_stack(vjust = 1.04)) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "Word")
plot
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Can also avoid coord_flip() nowadays by setting y = reorder(...), x = Frequency

Comment: Is there a way to do this without pre-calculating the frequency table? 

`data("diamonds"); diamonds %>% ggplot(aes(x = reorder(cut, ???)) + geom_bar()`